# Moving outward a range of numbers plotted on a curve line

Tags: r, plot

I was wondering how to make the **numbers currently plotted on the curve line** below to **move a bit outward** such that however `a` and `b` in my R code are changed the **distance between the numbers and the curve line remain the same (i.e., constant)?**

**Please see my R code below the following image:**

[image]

```
 a = 0  ;  b = 1

curve( dnorm(x, mean = a, sd = b ), -4, 4, axes = F, ann = F)

xx <- -4:4

yy <- dnorm(xx, mean = a, sd = b)

text(xx, yy, paste(round(yy, 2) ), font = 2 )
```

Comment: You should also have a look at the `offset` argument in the function `text`. This specifies the space between your text and the specified coordinates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As other colleagues also mentioned, the calculation of this distance can be taken care of by `text()` itself. One of the most suitable arguments in `text()` for this purpose is `pos`. Per R documentation `pos` takes 4 integer values, each of which move the text in one one of the 4 main directions: see `?text`. In this case, `3` produces the desired effect.

Thus, the following might resolve the problem:

```
  a = 0  ;  b = 1

 curve( dnorm(x, mean = a, sd = b ), -4, 4, axes = F, ann = F)

 xx <- -4:4

 yy <- dnorm(xx, mean = a, sd = b)

 text(xx, yy, paste(round(yy, 2) ), font = 2, pos = 3 )
```

Answer (score 2):

```
a = 0
b = 1

#Draw curve
curve(dnorm(x, mean = a, sd = b ), -4, 4, axes = F, ann = F)

#Assign curve to 'cc' and determine the length of points on the curve
cc = curve(dnorm(x, mean = a, sd = b ), -4, 4, axes = F, ann = F)
l_cc = length(cc$x)

xx <- -4:4
yy <- dnorm(xx, mean = a, sd = b)

#Find indices of values in cc$x closest ot xx
slope_inds = findInterval(xx, cc$x)

#Calculate approximate slope of cc for each xx
slope = numeric(0)
for (i in 1:length(slope_inds)){
    if (slope_inds[i] == 1){
        n = 1
    }else if (slope_inds[i] == l_cc){
        n = l_cc - 1
    }else{
        n = slope_inds[i]
    }
    slope[i] = round(diff(cc$y[n:(n+1)])/diff(cc$x[n:(n+1)]), 1)
}

#Assign pos value based on slope of cc. For ~zero slope, put text on top
# For other slopes assign values accordingly
positions = integer(0)
positions[slope == 0] = 3
positions[slope > 0] = 2
positions[slope < 0] = 4

#Write text
points(xx,yy)
text(xx, yy, paste(round(yy, 2) ), font = 2, pos = positions)
```